# 'Game.Server.GameObjects.GamePlayer' does not implement interface member 'Game.Logic.IGamePlayer.AddPrestige(bool)'

Tags: c#

Erro:

> 'Game.Server.GameObjects.GamePlayer' does not implement interface member 'Game.Logic.IGamePlayer.AddPrestige(bool)'

Código:

```
public class GamePlayer : IGamePlayer
{
    public void AddPrestige(bool isWin, eRoomType roomType)
    {
      if (roomType == eRoomType.RingStation)
      {
        UserRingStationInfo ringStationInfos = RingStationMgr.GetSingleRingStationInfos(this.PlayerCharacter.ID);
        if (ringStationInfos != null)
        {
          int num = RingStationMgr.ConfigInfo.AwardBattleByRank(ringStationInfos.get_Rank(), isWin);
          string translation = LanguageMgr.GetTranslation("Ringstasion.BattleLost", (object) num);
          if (isWin)
          {
            num = RingStationMgr.ConfigInfo.AwardBattleByRank(ringStationInfos.get_Rank(), isWin);
            translation = LanguageMgr.GetTranslation("Ringstasion.BattleWin", (object) num);
          }
          this.AddLeagueMoney(num);
          this.SendMessage(translation);
        }
      }
      if (roomType != eRoomType.BattleRoom)
        return;
      this.BattleData.AddPrestige(isWin);
    }
```

Postei resumido a vocês, porque o código inteiro tem mais de mil linhas, quem quiser o código inteiro comenta.

Comment: Por favor galera me ajudem, se precisar de mais coisas eu posto aqui

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPT. Você já teve uma resposta que certamente vai te ajudar, mas a qualidade da sua pergunta está bem baixa. Isso dificulta que as pessoas tenham interesse em responder. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e, principalmente, não deixe de ler [ask].

Answer (score 1):

O problema a assinatura do método `AddPrestige`, na interface tem apenas um parâmetro um `boolean` e a sua implementação do método recebe dois parâmetros, um `boolean` e um `eRoomType`.

Você precisa fazer com o que o seu método seja como a interface pede.

```
public void AddPrestige(bool isWin) { }
```

Pode ser que existam dois métodos com o mesmo, mas com assinaturas diferentes também. Neste caso, você precisa implementar os dois membros da interface.

Não tem como te ajudar mais porque você não deu mais detalhes sobre o problema.

Comment: Para isso teria que deletar o eRoomType? não teria como adicionar no outro código que no caso é este que está na IGamePlayer?:         void AddPrestige(bool isWin);
        void RingstationResult(bool isWin);

Comment: Se você tiver acesso à interface, pode mudar. Caso não tenha, você pode criar um método com o mesmo nome que tenha parâmetros diferentes (isso é chamado de overload).